# Feign call URL with comma

Tags: spring, feign, request-mapping

I'm trying to call a URL with commas, curly braces and square brackets in it.

With Feign, here is how I begin :

```
@FeignClient(name="FinancialTimesFeignClient", url="https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/ajax/updateScreenerResults")
public interface FinancialTimesClient {
    @GetMapping(value="?data=[a,b]")
    FinancialTimesDto getTickers();
}
```

The problem is that the url should end with `data=[a,b]` but I get this:

`GET /data/equities/ajax/updateScreenerResults?data=[a&data=b]`

It won't be understood by the server. Can I disable the rewriting?

Comment: does `[a,b]` really need to be hardcoded in the url or should it depends on some arguments passed to `getTickers` method ?

Comment: this needs to be hardcoded

Comment: Thank you @cerdoc ! I've been able to make it work by passing this table as a String RequestParam argument instead of the hardcoded form. Please answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the value of `data` as a String `RequestParam` to your method `getTickers` so that it will be append to the URL :

```java
...
 @GetMapping
 FinancialTimesDto getTickers(@RequestParam String data);
...
```